# Actionbarsherlock layout params (align NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS at bottom)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to use Actionbarsherlock to make tabs aligned at the bottom of a layout. Where the fragment views load above it instead of below it.

How would this be done? currently in `onCreate` I am doing

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`
```

and do not see an obvious function in `getSupportActionBar()` that facilitates its position onscreen.

Insight appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done. The tabs are built-in to the action bar which always remains at the top of the screen. The action bar behavior itself is dictated by the native action bar that's built-in to Android. ActionBarSherlock only mimics its behavior on pre-ICS.

If the native action bar does not support a feature then ActionBarSherlock will not be able to support it either.

A simpler way to do this would be to place a `TabWidget` at the bottom of the layout and theme them to look like the ICS-style tabs.

Comment: yes, you are right. I was trying to avoid the TabWidget. It has strange lifecycle features.... (and the actionbar was made to replace it, and actionbarsherlock was made to extend compatibility, le' sigh. the compatibility pack is no fun either)

Comment: I think you're thinking of `TabHost` or `TabActivity`. `TabWidget` is just a dumb control which acts like a radio button with a callback. I'm pretty sure it does almost nothing itself.